# Finding Unknown Variables in a Normal Distribution Hypothesis Test

Tags: statistics

I have a normal sample with -$\infty$ < $\mu$ < $\infty$ and 0 < $\sigma^2$ < $\infty$.

Null hypothesis: $H_0 : \sigma^2 = 1.$

Alternative hypothesis: $H_1 : \sigma^2 > 1.$

Test: Reject $H_0$  if $S^2 > k$

I'm struggling on how to find $k$ so that the test has size $\alpha$.

I know that I need to relate it to the Chi-squared distribution that has degree of freedom $n-1$, but am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Search the site please.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I searched the site and searched it again by looking at the similar questions that come up while you are making a title and nothing is coming up for me. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: This has been addressed in pretty much every question on this testing problem. Is $\mu$ known or unknown? If $\mu$ is unknown, then $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ with usual notation. And $P_{H_0}\left[S^2>k\right]=P_{H_0}\left[(n-1)S^2>(n-1)k\right]=P[\chi^2_{n-1}>(n-1)k]=\alpha$, which immediately gives $k$ in terms of chi-square quantiles.

Comment: @StubbornAtom and then I just need to solve for k, is that correct?

Comment: @StubbornAtom The question doesn't say anything about the value of mu so it is unknown. I put all the information in my original question. How do I go about solving for quartiles? We have never done this before.

Comment: $P[\chi^2_{n-1}>(n-1)k]=\alpha \implies (n-1)k=\chi^2_{n-1;\alpha}$. Here $\chi^2_{n-1;\alpha}$ is the $(1-\alpha)$th quantile or the upper $100\alpha\%$ point of a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution, i.e. $P[\chi^2_{n-1}>\chi^2_{n-1;\alpha}]=\alpha$. This gives a theoretical solution for $k$. Does this look familiar? I am guessing you have done something similar for normal distribution, if not for chi-square distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom we did some brief solving of quartiles when given the values of k and alpha but I don't recall doing anything like this. My teacher tends to brush over the solving part of the questions and only focuses on the main topic itself. Thank you for your help.